# .val() alternative that gets the current value of all elements in the set of matched elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-delegation

I have 3 select elements and I'm using `$(".select-elem select").val()` to get the value of each select element in an array but it returns the value of only the first element in the set of matched elements. For example, if a user selects '2' for the first select element, '3' for the second, and '4' for the third, the val() function returns `2` instead of `[2,3,4]`. Is there a function that would return an array containing values of all three select elements?

```
<td class="select-elem">
<select>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
</select>
</td>
<td class="select-elem">
<select>
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
</select>
</td>
<td class="select-elem">
<select>
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
</select>
</td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use map methods for this:

```
var values = $(".select-elem select").map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}).get();
```

Comment: This is the better answer than the accepted answer. No need to extend jQuery when there are methods such as `map` that do this for you

Answer (score 2):

Create your own jquery method and use it wherever you need, find the following code

```
//create jquery method arrVal which returns array of values
$.fn.arrVal = function () {
  var valArr = [];
  $(this).each(function(){
    valArr.push($(this).val())
  })
  return valArr;
}

//call arrVal method
$('select').arrVal()
```